# raspberry pi pip install psychopy HDF5 not found

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, ubuntu-18.04, psychopy

I'm trying to install psychopy on Raspberry Pi3b+ with Ubuntu MATE 18.04.04. Here's the error I'm getting while installing pytables.

The command I'm using: `sudo python3 -m pip install psychopy`

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-311swvsm/tables/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-311swvsm/tables/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-o9pwm6qh
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-311swvsm/tables/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    /tmp/H5close7m2miv9g.c:1:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
     main (int argc, char **argv) {
     ^~~~
    /tmp/H5close7m2miv9g.c: In function ‘main’:
    /tmp/H5close7m2miv9g.c:2:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘H5close’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         H5close();
         ^~~~~~~
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    * Using Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04)
    * USE_PKGCONFIG: False
    .. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
       You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
       library can be found by setting the ``HDF5_DIR`` environment
       variable or by using the ``--hdf5`` command-line option.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
lsp@lsp-raspi:~$
```

I'm very much a begginer, would you help me figure out what's the problem?
thanks in advance.

Few extra questions:

while installing psychopy with sudo I'm getting

```
WARNING: The directory '/home/lsp/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag
```

but the installation proceeds, will that be a problem in the future?

I'm not quite comfortable in with controling where installs what, I'm trying to control versions of the libraries by using `python3` command, is that enough for the libraries to install in respective locations?